# Can't store data from db.countDocuments in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm pretty new to Javascript, and I don't understand why I can't save the result of this code below.
I'm working with MongoDB and I want to store the number of documents in a cluster so that I can keep track of how many are in the cluster, however, when I try to log the output on the third line, it is undefined. Why is this?

```
let theIndex;
collection.countDocuments({}).then(res => theIndex = res);
console.log(theIndex);
```

Answer (score 2):

`collection.countDocuments({})` returns a promise so you should use `console.log` once it resolves:

```
collection.countDocuments({}).then(res => {
 theIndex = res;
 console.log(theIndex);
});
```

The callback function inside `.then` is executed once the promise resolves. Logging it outside the callback won't work because that `console.log` line gets executed immediately and at a later point of time(because reaching the database and such takes time) the callback is called.

Note that even if the promise resolves immediately(as fast as possible), the callback still gets executed later because of the event loop in javascript.